# How to see the public information of your Facebook app users?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created a Facebook application and I use it in my own website. I know I ask people for their 'public information' before they start using my application. How can I see this public information after they have accepted my application?

Can I do this from the facebook app perfil or via javascript?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can view the public information using the JavaScript by performing a GET request to the Graph API using the `FB.api` method.

It looks like you are new to the Javascript API. Take a look at the [JavaScript Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript) and [FB.api method](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/). It's pretty easy to use once the user has been authenticated.